# How can I put this logo in the center of the page with the image to the side of it while everything is lined up?

Tags: html, css

So I cant seem to figure out this padding, margin, and flexbox thing I cant seem to get these last 2 pictures lined up like this[image] at the bottom of the page (green part). I need to put the logo in the middle and the photo right beside it. Also the code starts from < div class="bottom"> down.

```css
/*
Colors:

Text: 1A1A1A
Green: #00B172
White: #FFF

*/
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 35vw;
}

nav > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #070707;
}


.logo-spotify{
    height: auto;
    width: 10vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}

.start{
    background-image: url(../images/landing.jpg);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 850px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.start-texts-Music{
    color: white;
    margin: 5vh 0;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.start-texts-Para{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

h2{
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #06bc7d;
    margin: 4vh 37vw;
}

.ads{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 10vh 5.5vw;
}

.ads-block{
    text-align: center;
    
}

.ads-text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #06bc7d;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.ads-desc{
    margin: 3vh 0 3vh 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 13vw;
    color: #8a8a8a;
}

.bottom{
    width: auto;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    background-color: #06bc7d;
    margin: 0 2vw;
}

h3{
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    margin: 0 52vw 0 10vw;
    
} 

.bottom-search{
    padding: 5vh 5vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 30vw;
    margin: 0;

}

.title-search{
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3vw;
}
.desc-search{
    color: white;
    padding: 3vh 0;
    font-size: 1vw;
    max-width: 25vw;
    margin: 0;
}

.center-bottom{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    /* padding-bottom: 50vh; */
} 

/* .middle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 600px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
} */

.icon-white{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.app{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.app-pic{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Spotify Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img
        class="logo-spotify"
        src="images/spotify-logo.png"
        alt="logo-spotify"
      />
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Premium</a>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
        <a href="#">Download</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="start">
      <h1 class="start-texts-Music">Music for everyone.</h1>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Spotify is now free on mobile, tablet and computer.
      </p>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Listen to the right music, wherever you are.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2>What’s on Spotify?</h2>
    <div class="ads">
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/music-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Millions of Songs</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">There are millions of songs on Spotify</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img
          src="images/high-quality-icon.png"
          alt=""
          height="auto"
          width="150px"
        />
        <p class="ads-text">HD Music</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">Listen to music as if you were listening live</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/devices-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Stream Everywhere</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">
          Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <h3>It’s as yeezy as Kanye West.</h3>
      <div class="bottom-search">
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">search</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Know what you want to listen to? <br />
            Just search and hit play.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">Browse</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Check out the latest charts, <br />
            brand new releases and great <br />
            playlists for right now.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">Discover</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Enjoy new music every Monday <br />
            with your own personal playlist. <br />
            Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-bottom">
        <div class="middle">
          <img
            class="icon-white"
            src="images/spotify-icon-white.png"
            alt=""
            height="auto"
            width="100px"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="app">
        <img
          class="app-pic"
          src="images/spotify-app.jpg"
          alt=""
          width="auto"
          height="700px"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <p>
      Discover Help Download Music for everyone. Spotify is now free on mobile,
      tablet and computer. Listen to the right music, wherever you are. What’s
      on Spotify? Millions of Songs There are millions of songs on Spotify HD
      Music Listen to music as if you were listening live Stream Everywhere
      Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer It’s as yeezy as Kanye
      West. Search Know what you want to listen to? Just search and hit play.
      Browse Check out the latest charts, brand new releases and great playlists
      for right now. Discover Enjoy new music every Monday with your own
      personal playlist. Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
    </p> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

So far this is what mine looks like [image] and last but not least i cant get this stupid "yeezy" title [image] to look like the one in the photo i put. Mine has no spacing from the green part and when i try the margin or padding goes outside the green area.

Comment: can you give me the apk picture?

Comment: If I am not wrong that you forgot to add display:flex in .bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have it, hope it helps

```css
/*
Colors:

Text: 1A1A1A
Green: #00B172
White: #FFF

*/
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 35vw;
}

nav>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #070707;
}


.logo-spotify {
  height: auto;
  width: 5vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.start {
  background-image: url(../images/landing.jpg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 850px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.start-texts-Music {
  color: white;
  margin: 5vh 0;
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.start-texts-Para {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

h2 {
  /* text-decoration: underline; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #06bc7d;
  margin: 4vh 37vw;
}

.ads {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10vh 5.5vw;
}

.ads-block {
  text-align: center;

}

.ads-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #06bc7d;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.ads-desc {
  margin: 3vh 0 3vh 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 13vw;
  color: #8a8a8a;
}

.bottom {
  width: auto;
  /* height: 100vh; */
  background-color: #06bc7d;
  margin: 0 2vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;

}

.bottom-search {
  padding: 5vh 5vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 30vw;
  margin: 0;
  grid-column: span 5 / span 5;
}

.title-search {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.desc-search {
  color: white;
  padding: 3vh 0;
  font-size: 1vw;
  max-width: 25vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.center-bottom {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* padding-bottom: 50vh; */
  grid-column: span 2 / span 2;
  grid-column-start: 6;
}

/* .middle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 600px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 100vh;
} */

.icon-white {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  grid-column-start: 8;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  grid-column: span 5 / span 5;
}

.app-pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Spotify Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img class="logo-spotify" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/spotify-logo-png/spotify-icon-marilyn-scott-0.png" alt="logo-spotify" />
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Premium</a>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
        <a href="#">Download</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="start">
      <h1 class="start-texts-Music">Music for everyone.</h1>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Spotify is now free on mobile, tablet and computer.
      </p>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Listen to the right music, wherever you are.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2>What’s on Spotify?</h2>
    <div class="ads">
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/music-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Millions of Songs</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">There are millions of songs on Spotify</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/high-quality-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">HD Music</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">Listen to music as if you were listening live</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/devices-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Stream Everywhere</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">
          Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">

      <div class="bottom-search">
        <h3>It’s as yeezy as Kanye West.</h3>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">search</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Know what you want to listen to? <br />
            Just search and hit play.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">Browse</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Check out the latest charts, <br />
            brand new releases and great <br />
            playlists for right now.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">Discover</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Enjoy new music every Monday <br />
            with your own personal playlist. <br />
            Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="center-bottom">
        <div class="middle">
          <img class="icon-white" src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/spotify-logo-png/spotify-icon-marilyn-scott-0.png" alt="" height="auto" width="100px" />
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="app">
        <img class="app-pic" src="https://imag.malavida.com/mvimgbig/download-fs/spotify-10520-1.jpg" alt="" width="auto" height="700px" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- <p>
      Discover Help Download Music for everyone. Spotify is now free on mobile,
      tablet and computer. Listen to the right music, wherever you are. What’s
      on Spotify? Millions of Songs There are millions of songs on Spotify HD
      Music Listen to music as if you were listening live Stream Everywhere
      Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer It’s as yeezy as Kanye
      West. Search Know what you want to listen to? Just search and hit play.
      Browse Check out the latest charts, brand new releases and great playlists
      for right now. Discover Enjoy new music every Monday with your own
      personal playlist. Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
    </p> -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Spotify Clone</title>
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <img
        class="logo-spotify"
        src="images/spotify-logo.png"
        alt="logo-spotify"
      />
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Premium</a>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
        <a href="#">Download</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="start">
      <h1 class="start-texts-Music">Music for everyone.</h1>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Spotify is now free on mobile, tablet and computer.
      </p>
      <p class="start-texts-Para">
        Listen to the right music, wherever you are.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h2>What’s on Spotify?</h2>
    <div class="ads">
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/music-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Millions of Songs</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">There are millions of songs on Spotify</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img
          src="images/high-quality-icon.png"
          alt=""
          height="auto"
          width="150px"
        />
        <p class="ads-text">HD Music</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">Listen to music as if you were listening live</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ads-block">
        <img src="images/devices-icon.png" alt="" height="auto" width="150px" />
        <p class="ads-text">Stream Everywhere</p>
        <p class="ads-desc">
          Stream music on your smartphone, tablet or computer
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="bottom-search-wrap">
        <h3>It’s as yeezy as Kanye West.</h3>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">search</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Know what you want to listen to? <br />
            Just search and hit play.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">Browse</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Check out the latest charts, <br />
            brand new releases and great <br />
            playlists for right now.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-search">
          <div class="title-search">Discover</div>
          <p class="desc-search">
            Enjoy new music every Monday <br />
            with your own personal playlist. <br />
            Or sit back and enjoy Radio.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="center-bottom">
        <div class="middle">
          <img
            class="icon-white"
            src="images/spotify-icon-white.png"
            alt=""
            height="auto"
            width="100px"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="app">
        <img
          class="app-pic"
          src="images/spotify-app.png"
          alt=""
          width="auto"
          height="700px"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 35vw;
}

nav > a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #070707;
}


.logo-spotify{
    height: auto;
    width: 10vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}

.start{
    background-image: url(../images/landing.jpg);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 850px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.start-texts-Music{
    color: white;
    margin: 5vh 0;
    font-size: 5vw;
}

.start-texts-Para{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

h2{
    /* text-decoration: underline; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #06bc7d;
    margin: 4vh 37vw;
}

.ads{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 10vh 5.5vw;
}

.ads-block{
    text-align: center;
    
}

.ads-text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #06bc7d;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

.ads-desc{
    margin: 3vh 0 3vh 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 13vw;
    color: #8a8a8a;
}

/* New Style Start============ */
.bottom{ background-color: #06bc7d; margin: 0 50px; padding: 40px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: stretch; }
.bottom h3{color: white;font-size: 40px;border-bottom: 2px solid white;margin: 0 0 20px 0;}
.bottom .bottom-search{padding: 0 0 20px 0;margin: 0;}

.bottom .title-search{color: white;margin: 0;font-size: 3vw;}
.bottom .desc-search{color: white;padding: 0 0;font-size: 1vw;margin: 0;}

.bottom .center-bottom{ display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }
```